# Rails console and displaying results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I am connected to the server through a terminal session on my Windows 10 PC.

I start a Rails console session:

```
rails c
```

I get the rails console prompt, and then I type:

@ticket = Ticket.find_by_id(15)

I get the results. Then I type:

```
@ticket.methods
```

To get a listing of the available methods. The first 25 or 50 results get displayed, and then I can page through it, eventually I reach the end and I see (END) displayed. I cannot do anything else. Hitting return will do nothing, CTRL-C does nothing, the only thing I can do is CTRL-Z and that terminates the console session.

Are there options not to do a partial display of results, and how do I get out of this display mode without having to terminate the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think hitting `q` should do the trick.